# Find which process use old DNS server on centos

Tags: centos, dns

Context : I just installed 2 new DNS servers and some production servers still query the old one even after changing the configuration.
I had to change the configuration at the application level for some of them and it worked well.
For the remaining servers I need to find which process is still misconfigured.

- I tried with `netstat -apcn | grep udp` but DNS query is too fast for anything to show.
  Same problem with `lsof -i UDP`
- I was thinking about `tcpdump` but I don't think it will show me any process.
- I have seen some solutions using `auditctl` but it's 11 years old and nontrivial.

Is there a simple way of seeing which process send DNS request ?

(If it helps, I have access to logs on DNS servers, old and new ones)

Comment: Maybe try adding a temporary firewall rule on the production server(s), or one the old DNS server itself, blocking **udp** port 53 to the old DNS server.  If you're lucky, that **may** cause the guilty process to attempt **tcp** 53 instead...which would be easier to spot in netstat.

Comment: Why not just add a firewall rule to log all requests to port 53 on the old server?

Comment: because finding the **process** sending the dns requests is the goal, not just the IP address of the sender (that's easily logged).   tcp connections are easier to trace back to a process id/name than udp, if only because they take longer and there's two-way communication to establish the connection.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion I certainly will try it and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking the logs on the DNS server. If it's not logging the queries then turn on logging. You didn't tell us what DNS server it was so we can't give a specific answer on how to do that.

Comment: I already have logs on the DNS side, but it won't tell me anything about the process that is sending it (I don't want the IP of the server, I need the process name on this server).